# Error converting date while resuming Biztalk instance

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

When I try to resume BizTalk instance, I am getting the following error from BT console:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have BizTalk server 2013 and MsgBox DB on different servers.

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: Can you give more details about the error? Is this the error the instance gives or is this actually the biztalk console?

Comment: Are you sure time synchronization between your BizTalk server and SQL server is setup fine? And how about your SQL collation? Did you recently restore your BizTalk databases? We will need some more information in order to be able to have proper insight in the problem.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, yeah thats Biztalks console error.

Comment: @PieterVandenheede Should time between BT Server and BT database server be synchronized? I haven't done any database restores. That problem occures in my client's test environment. I do also suspect that the reason is collation, but it is same for all BT databases(SSODB,BiztalkMgmtDb,BiztalkMsgBox,BiztalkDTADb). Is there some other places, where i should specify collation?

Comment: @ArsenMagomedov We always recommend to do time synchronization for our clients between all SQL/BTS servers to avoid any mismatches. We did already have some issues because of this. How about the collation of your BAM databases and such? Have you tried investigating with SQL profiler to see where it goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out, that when user resumes an instance, Biztalk executes stored proc, and passes some   varchar values (like '2014-08-14 06:52:47.247', which is not using language independent date string format) to it's datetime parameters. The nvarchar->datetime conversion behaviour depends on server @@LANGUAGE and DATEFORMAT properties, which were set to Russian.
I've changed default server language of SQL Server with msg box to us_english, and changed default language for all SQL logins on that server to us_english.
That solved the problem